# Call an AJAX load from another AJAX load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a page A, which passes form parameters to a script which does an AJAX load of the results into div B on page A. This works. I want to extend it to have another form in div B, which passes parameters to another script which should do an AJAX load of the results in div C on page A.  I can't get this to work.

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768673/ajax-inside-an-ajax-success) was the closest I could find, but that seems to deal with an automatic call to the second AJAZ load, whereas here I have a form intervening.

The working code, which uses Prototype, is:

### first.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
<script>
Ajax.Responders.register({
    onCreate: function(){ Element.show('spinner')},
    onComplete: function(){Element.hide('spinner')}
});
</script>

<form id="first_form">
<input  /> etc etc
<input type="button" onclick="first_box()" value="Call get_first_data.php">
</form>

<script>
function first_box(){
    new Ajax.Updater( 
        'first_div',
        'get_first_data.php', { 
            method: 'post',
            parameters: $('first_form').serialize()
    });
}
</script>

<div id="first_div">
    <p>The output from get_first_data.php appears here.</p>
    <img alt="spinner" id="spinner" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" style="display:none;" />
</div>
```

For the proposed extension, I want to call another script from the get_first_data output in the first.php first_text div,, and have the output of that also show in first.php.  I've done the following (basically copying the above, edited, to the top of get_first_data.php), but it's not working.

### get_first_data.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
<script>
Ajax.Responders.register({
    onCreate: function(){ Element.show('spinner')},
    onComplete: function(){Element.hide('spinner')}
});
</script>

<form id="second_form">
<input  /> etc etc
<input type="button" onclick="second_box()" value="Call get_second_data.php">
</form>

<script>
function second_box(){
    new Ajax.Updater( 
        'second_div',
        'get_second_data.php', { 
            method: 'post',
            parameters: $('second_form').serialize()
    });
}
</script>

<div id="second_div">
    <p>The get_second_data output should appear here, but doesn't.</p>
    <img alt="spinner" id="spinner" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" style="display:none;" />
</div>

... rest of the get_first_data.php output ...
```

Finally, what would be the JQuery equivalent of the Prototype code here?

Comment: why not store results from ajax call one to a variable then pass that var into the second function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that I understood your question right.

You say *"I want to call another script from the get_first_data output in the first.php"*. Why would you want this, since the get_first_data content is loaded on-demand, e.g. would not be at any moment at your disposal? Anyway, it is a normal workflow to define js/jquery scripts in a page loaded by an ajax request. The code below implements it. I also added a "callSecondBoxButton" button in *first.php*, which calls the *second_box()* function defined in the ajax loaded *get_first_data.php* page. So, the *second_box()* function can be called both from *first.php* and *get_first_data.php*.

I am not familiarized with the *Prototype* representation, but the *jQuery* code would be as below.

You might want to use the *camelCase* notation for the *id* attributes and to refine the error handling to only show a user-friendly message.

#### first.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo - first</title>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document)
                    .ready(function () {
                        $('#spinner').hide();

                        $('#firstButton').click(function (event) {
                            first_box();
                        });

                        $('#callSecondBoxButton').click(function (event) {
                            if (typeof second_box === 'function') {
                                second_box();
                            } else {
                                alert('The "second_box" function is not (yet) defined!');
                            }
                        });
                    })
                    .ajaxStart(function () {
                        $('#spinner').show();
                    })
                    .ajaxStop(function () {
                        $('#spinner').hide();
                    });

            function first_box() {
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'post',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    url: 'get_first_data.php',
                    data: $('#first_form').serialize(),
                    success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        $('#first_div').html(response);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $('#first_div').html(textStatus + '<br />' + errorThrown);
                    },
                    complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        //...
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form id="first_form">
            <input type="text" value="abc" />
            <input type="button" id="firstButton" value="Call get_first_data.php">
            <input type="button" id="callSecondBoxButton" value="Call second_box() from first.php">
        </form>

        <div id="first_div">
            <p>
                The output from get_first_data.php appears here.
            </p>
            <img alt="spinner" id="spinner" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

#### get_first_data.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#secondButton').click(function (event) {
            second_box();
        });
    });

    function second_box() {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: 'get_second_data.php',
            data: $('#second_form').serialize(),
            success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#second_div').html(response);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#second_div').html(textStatus + '<br />' + errorThrown);
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                //...
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<hr />

<form id="second_form">
    <input type="text" value="def" />
    <input type="button" id="secondButton" value="Call get_second_data.php">
</form>

<div id="second_div">
    <p>
        The output from get_second_data.php should appear here, but it doesn't.
    </p>
    <img alt="spinner" id="spinner" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />
</div>
```

#### get_second_data.php

```
<hr />

<div>
    I am the content/data of get_second_data.php.
</div>
```

Comment: For the users who, maybe, decide to downvote my answer: Please let me know the motive of your downvote, so that I can change my answer correspondingly. I am opened to all your suggestions or critiques, but please be fair and give me the chance of knowing your perspective. This way we can contribute together to the continuous improvement of this website. Thank you.

Comment: Why on earth was this downvoted?  It is a detailed answer that does exactly what I needed - thank you so much, @dakis!  The reason I need to do it in two steps is that the first form collects settings for data output, and once that is done then the user can click to create a pdf of that custom output.  Once edited to suit my setup, this works great!

Comment: @donnek You are welcome. The downvote came too quickly; therefore having nothing to do with my answer, imho. Important is, that I could help you. Good luck further! :-)

Comment: @donnek I just read the rest of your comment. So, in your project, in principle, will you apply the "strategy" of using the _callSecondBoxButton_ button (in _first.php_), or the _secondButton_ button (in _get_first_data.php_)? Personally, I would use the second option. I would say that the first one would be suitable if you would work with default pdf settings too. Then you could define _second_box()_ directly in _first.php_.

Comment: Yes, I have to use the second option (the secondButton button in get_first_data.php), because the user may choose different settings each time.

Comment: @donnek Ok. Have fun. Bye.